# Strange array_diff results

Tags: php

I'm getting some data from various db tables using codeigniter. Funny thing is that 10 lines above this code I was testing the concept with some other arrays which had names and everything worked as expected. Now that I'm trying the same thing with the data from my db it doesn't seem to be working.

**Code**

```
            echo "a:";print_r($CITB);
            echo "<br />b:";print_r($PRB);
            echo "<br />c:";print_r($TB);
            echo "<br />d:";print_r($TRB);


            $a = $CITB; //I know this is empty
            $b = array_diff($PRB,$a);
            $c = array_diff($TB, $b, $a);
            $d = array_diff($TRB, $c, $b, $a);

             echo "<br /><br />a:";print_r($a);
             echo "<br />b:";print_r($b);
             echo "<br />c:";print_r($c);
             echo "<br />d:";print_r($d);die();
```

**Result**

```
a:
b:Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 52 ) 
c:Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 52 ) 
d:

a:
b:
c:
d:
```

**Expected result**

```
a:Array()
b:Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 52 ) 
c:Array()
d:Array()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to array_diff should be arrays. Otherwise it will return `null`.

In your case `print_r($CITB);` doesn't print as `Array()` which means it is not an empty array and most likely an empty string. So `$b = array_diff($PRB,$a);` results in `$b` being `null`.

If you turn on error reporting you should see some warnings. Otherwise use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to see the types for the variables.

Comment: Oh you are right, that's because I'm 'if' checking whether there is data in the db, and not defining the $CITB as a variable, so it ends up as an empty string. Thanks for that quick tip!